# Unable to create an instance of TimePicker class

Tags: java, android

`DialogFragment timepicker = new TimePicker();`

`DialogFragment timepicker = new com.example.alarm.TimePicker();`

I want to know is there any difference between these two lines of codes??

The first one is saying cannot resolve constructor 'TimePicker'

The second line is working fine. But is there any difference?

Answer (score 0):

the error means that you did not import the package while calling the constructor on line 1.
And the second is working because you called the function by specifying the package !
Do an import com.example.alarm then do DialogFragment timepicker = new TimePicker(); it will work or either import the appropriate package containing TimePicker class before instanciating it.